# Which ESRI Silverlight API version goes with which Silverlight version?

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api

I am trying to get my references right in a Silverlight app. I cannot find the ESRI Silverlight API goes with Silverlight 3. I can only find the latest version of the ESRI Silverlight API (Version 2.4).

So the Question boils down to which ESRI Silverlight API version goes with which Silverlight version? And where can I download the ESRI Silverlight API?

Just as a sidenote. The [ArcGIS Silverlight toolkit](http://esrisilverlight.codeplex.com/) seems to following the API version (please correct me if I'm wrong) and all the versions are downloadable from [codeplex](http://codeplex.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on and an answer on [twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/dotMorten/status/162551468979798017) from Morten Nielsen (one of the maintainer of [ArcGIS Silverlight Toolkit](http://esrisilverlight.codeplex.com/) the 1.1 and 1.2 versions of the esri silverlight API works with Silverlight 3.

The 1.2 version is still available for download (at present time of writing) from http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgis-api-silverlightwpf/1.2/about (signup for a global esri account is needed.)

Except for the newest version (4.2) and the 1.2 version of the esri silverlight API I have not been able to find any version available for download.

The 4.2 version works with Silverlight 4. It can be downloaded at http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/index.html